# Authenticating a REST request in an Excel Add-in

Tags: excel, office-js

I am trying to develop an add-in for Excel with the goal that it will create calendar events based on data inside a spreadsheet.

I can do almost everything that I want except use the REST API to build the events in the calendar and I can't exactly figure out where I went wrong.

I have followed the [documentation suggested by @MarcLaFleur](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs).

I can build and run the application no problem, but when I click on the 'Get my files from OneDrive' button, I get the following:

```
Code: 5001
Message: An internal error has occurred.
name: Internal Error
```

This is coming from the program.js file in the public directory somewhere in the else clause of this function.

```cs
function getDataWithoutAuthChallenge() {
    Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync({ forceConsent: false },
        function (result) {
            if (result.status === "succeeded") {
                // TODO1: Use the access token to get Microsoft Graph data.
                accessToken = result.value;
                getData("/api/onedriveitems", accessToken);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Code: " + result.error.code);
                console.log("Message: " + result.error.message);
                console.log("name: " + result.error.name);
                document.getElementById("getGraphAccessTokenButton").disabled = true;
            }
        });
}
```

Here are the scopes in my `manifest.xml`

```xml
    ...
    <WebApplicationInfo>
      <Id>c931b396-7 ... </Id>
      <Resource>api://localhost:3000/c931b396-7 ... </Resource>
      <Scopes>
        <Scope>files.read.all</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
      </Scopes>
    </WebApplicationInfo>
  </VersionOverrides>
```

And here are the scopes on `apps.dev.microsoft.com`:

[image: Imgur]

If you can shed any light for me, it would really help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5001 error often suggests something fundamentally wrong with the add-in API in Office. For example, your Office app doesn't support the API, the manifest is incorrect, or the version of office.js doesn't work with it. Since you're using the sample, two things come to mind:

1. You aren't running the latest [Insiders
   build](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider)
2. The wrong manifest is getting loaded (this sometimes happens if you're
   on Windows and using a version of Visual Studio 2017 that has old
   schema files, so you have to do a post-build clean up of the debug
   Manifest XML)

Your manifest and Azure registration look mostly good, though Rick's comment about Scopes is relevant. profile must work with openid as a pair (profile alone won't work; openid alone won't work), and as discussed you need this consented. As the developer, you can try [consenting for yourself at the protocol level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code). You’ll want to update the client_id, redirect_uri, and scope query parameters as appropriate, and add &prompt=consent.

To answer a later question, Excel and Mail add-ins are different, and my answer only applies to Excel. For Outlook there's a [different sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-attachments-demo).

Comment: I still have not resolved this, but SO requires me to award the bounty and my problem definitely has something to do with the way the administrative settings.

Answer (score 2):

5001 can be caused by not requesting **profile** scope. You need to request the **profile** scope in addition to **Calendar.ReadWrite**. You do this when you register the app, as well as in the manifest. For more information, see the articles that Marc LaFleur linked to.

Comment: Thanks, I think I may be making it too hard on myself. Is it possible to use both the excel add in workbook and the Outlook mailbox in the context of the same add in?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation can be found at [Enable single sign-on for Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins). There is also walk though for both [ASP.NET](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet) and [Node.js](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs) as well documentation on [Troubleshooting](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins).

There are a number of things that could be going wrong here but without knowing more about your registration it is difficult to determine. That said, here are a couple of common mistakes:

- You'll need to make sure you receive [Admin Consent](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs#grant-admin-consent-to-the-add-in) for the tenant you're developing against. This is only a dev requirement and won't be required once your publish to the Store.
- Make sure you've pre-authorized the correct applications. You'll need pre-authorizations for:

  - d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c (Microsoft Office)
  - 57fb890c-0dab-4253-a5e0-7188c88b2bb4 (Office Online)
  - bc59ab01-8403-45c6-8796-ac3ef710b3e3 (Office Online)
- Make sure the scopes you're defining in your `manifest.xml` are reflected in the app registration at `apps.dev.microsoft.com`.
- If you make changes to your permission scopes, you need to make sure you repeat the Admin Consent process. When you receive consent, they are consenting to the scopes that were registered at the time of consent rather than the App ID itself.

Comment: Is it possible to get a token without requiring a user to use single sign on? For example, an excel add-in that opens a task pane and can create calendar events? My users are already signed into excel, so I don't want to require sign on again inside the add-on. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it possible to incorporate both Outlook and Excel in the same add in without using SSO? Thanks

Comment: How do people generally get the admin consent for a tenant they are developing for if they are not at the physical location with an admin?

Comment: Admin Consent is executed by having an Admin open a URL, entering their credentials and accepting the scopes you're requesting. I have a walk through that might be helpful: http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/

Comment: For SSO in Office Add-ins, you can leverage the existing user. See https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins for information on how this works.

Comment: Marc, I finally got Admin Consent and the tenant id and I went all the way through the tutorial, but I am still getting "Code: 5001 Message: An internal error has occurred. name: Internal Error" at the end. Could this be because I am not on the domain I am developing for? I am logged into my account, but not on the same network.

Comment: Your domain shouldn't matter, only the account you've signed into Office with. A couple of things that would help if you could include with your question: 1) The scopes from your manifest.xml (or just a link to the entire manifest if that is easier), 2) A screen shot of your registration from `apps.dev.microsoft.com` that shows the scopes defined, 3) A Fiddler trace capturing the calls at the protocol level.

Comment: I updated my post to contain the manifest scopes and a screenshot. I have never used Fiddler before so I'm not sure which data is helpful from that program.

Comment: Your scopes look okay to me but I suspect you need to re-apply Admin Consent. I've added a bullet point to my answer that explains but I suspect `profile` isn't getting included in your token because it was added after you received consent for `Files.Read.All`.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help @Marc LaFleur. I have asked for admin consent again, but that may take a few days :( Frustrating to not be an admin!