# Using SSO (getAccessTokenAsync) getting error 5001

Tags: single-sign-on, office-js, office-addins, officedev

I was trying to run the sso example for nodejs https://github.com/officedev/office-add-in-nodejs-sso and when I call the API for getting the token(this line):

Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync({forceConsent: false},

I am getting the error 5001. I am testing the add-in using office on-line.

Thanks for your helo

Comment: Can you show the full error trace? Also, if you can write here (instead of linking) your code would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authenticating a REST request in an Excel Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010523/authenticating-a-rest-request-in-an-excel-add-in)

Answer (score 0):

After giving permissions by administrator account problem solved.

Comment: But Outlook for Desktop is still giving me the error 13003.

Comment: How did the admin give permission? Struck with the same error. would be helpful if your issue is resolved.